# Google Sign In GoogleIdToken back-end verification suddenly fails

Tags: java, android, token, google-signin

I always had this issue with Google Sign In. I have an Android app that the user connects uses to authenticate with Google and then send the idToken to my server. The server uses the library provided by Google (GoogleIdTokenVerifier) to verify the token.

```
   GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
            .setAudience(audience)
            .setIssuer("https://accounts.google.com")
            .build();

    GoogleIdToken idToken = null;

    try {
        idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (idToken != null) {
        GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
        String userId = payload.getSubject();
        System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);
        String email = payload.getEmail();
        System.out.println("Emaail:" + email);
        return userId;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
        return null;
    }
```

This worked for a while, then suddenly the validation started to always fail. Nothing has changed!
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have similar problem, it worked before, code has not changed but now token verification fails at first attempts. Later, after ~10s, the same token becomes valid and returns user information.

Comment: I just switched to using the REST api for that..

Comment: It works for me now with the same code. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461832/google-sign-in-googleidtokenverifier-verifies-token-with-delay

Answer (score 3):

Check your server time, I had the same issue when I migrated to a new server. I solved the issue by setting the time zone using NTP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running over your localhost, check if your computers hour its correct, on the same timezone as the server.

I spent a complete day with this bug, getting null from the idToken sent to the client.